# How do I force macOS to update?

Tags: macos, software-update

How do I force macOS to update? When I try to open Xcode I get the message that I'm not running a new enough version of macOS. However, the software updater menu says I'm up-to-date.

[image: You have macOS 10.14 this application requires 10.14.4]

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to download an update manually.

Generally speaking Apple releases what they call *combo updates* that will update all previous versions of an OS release to the (current) latest version.

You can search out "Mac OS 14 combo update" and you will end up here:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2000?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

With the latest revision of macOS Mojave 14.5.

This also works with previous versions of macOS. Combo updates are also a good way to fix a "misbehaving" OS installation.

Comment: It says that it can only install on an APFS-formatted drive.

Comment: Latest is 10.14.6 btw - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2010

Comment: https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos for complete index.